# Detecting if a group of words was mentioned

Tags: php, filter

I would like to know if there's anyway of detecting if a group of words was mentioned in a string with **PHP**. Let's suppose that it's allowed to say "assault" but  "assault+rifle" isn't. So...

`"I saw an assault"` shouldn't be detected

`"I bought an assault rifle"` should

`"I assaulted a bank with my rifle"` also should

Comment: There is nothing you can do reliably. You can check that all the words in a specific phrase exist in the target string, but you would still have trouble with either being too strict (assume that `assaulted` contains `assault` which it does, but then the word `grape` also contains `rape`; an example I've actually seen somewhere) or too lenient (match whole words only, but miss valid variations like assault->assaulted or assaults). Also, neither of these would stop character substitutions like `assauIt` where the `L` was replaced with an upper case `i` (damn serif fonts after save).

Answer (score 2):

A common way would be to split the input string (i.e `"assault+rifle"`) by `"+"`s, then for each of those, check if it is in the original text.

```
// Assuming:
$text;
$words;

// Iterating through the splitted $words
foreach(explode("+", $words) as &$word) {
    // Checking if the text contains our word
    if (strpos($text, $word) === false)) {
        die("Allowed");
    }
}
echo "Not Allowed";
```

Comment: The example will stop on the first found word, not if all words are found.

Comment: Will you propose a fix? @JonathanKuhn

Comment: Wrap it in a function and loop over each word and when one isn't found, return false. Else, all were found and return true. Your concept is correct though, you need to check each word individually but you need to check all words to make sure they all exist before assuming it is not allowed.

Comment: @JonathanKuhn Ah, got it. Thought you meant something else... I think I fixed it, though.

Comment: Yea, that's it. You would also just want to make your comparisson type sensitive with `===` so that if the pos is `0` that doesn't return true.

Comment: Whoops, I was sure I did ;) Probably dropped it by mistake